# Como fazer um SUM em campos de tabelas diferentes no Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Essa é a `SQL` que tenho como exemplo, gostaria de fazer a mesma com `Linq`?

```
select SUM(iv.precoMediano * oi.quantidade) as total from orc_orcamentoItem oi
inner join orc_insumoValor iv on oi.codigo = iv.codigoSinapi
where oi.grupoPai = 1 
group by oi.grupoPai
```

A minha dúvida principal nisso é:    Como fazer o Sum no linq usando Campos das duas tabelas.            Por exemplo: Sum(tabela1=> tabela1.quantidade * tabela2.valor)

Entidades

Orçamento item

```
public int Item_id { get; set; }
public int Orcamento_id { get; set; }
public string Tipo_desc { get; set; }
public string Descricao { get; set; }
public int GrupoPai { get; set; }
public int Codigo { get; set; }
public decimal Quantidade { get; set; }
public string base_desc { get; set; }
```

Insumo Valor

```
public int InsumoDados_id { get; set; }
public int InsumoValor_id { get; set; }
public int CodigoSinapi { get; set; }
public string OrigemPreco { get; set; }
public decimal PrecoMediano { get; set; }
```

Comment: Seria legal você disponibilizar também os `Models` para ter uma resposta bem próxima da realidade.

Comment: 1 Orcamento Item tem 1 Insumo Valor? qual é o tipo de relação?

Comment: Sim. Elas são ligadas pelo campo código.

Comment: A minha dúvida principal nisso é:    Como fazer o Sum no linq usando Campos das duas tabelas.            Por exemplo: Sum(tabela1=> tabela1.quantidade * tabela2.valor)

Comment: Elas são ligadas pelo campo código mas, por exemplo um item só tem um valor? faltou também colocar isso no seus models

Comment: Virgilio, muito obrigado pelo interesse em ajudar.

A resposta do MurariAlex resolveu o meu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue abaixo a versão em `LINQ` e as tabelas que utilizei neste exemplo.

**Query LINQ**

```
var result = from oi in ctx.OrcamentoItem // onde ctx é o contexto do EF 
             join iv in ctx.InsumoValor on oi.Codigo equals iv.CodigoSinapi
             where oi.GrupoPai == 1
             group new { oi, iv } by oi.GrupoPai into grp
             select new
             {
                Total = grp.Sum(t => t.oi.Quantidade * t.iv.PrecoMediano)
             };
```

**Classes**

```
public class OrcamentoItem
{
    public int Item_id { get; set; }
    public int Orcamento_id { get; set; }
    public string Tipo_desc { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int GrupoPai { get; set; }
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantidade { get; set; }
    public string base_desc { get; set; }
}

public class InsumoValor
{
    public int InsumoDados_id { get; set; }
    public int InsumoValor_id { get; set; }
    public int CodigoSinapi { get; set; }
    public string OrigemPreco { get; set; }
    public decimal PrecoMediano { get; set; }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tCNtxH)

Comment: Ótimo.
Era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando. 
Obrigado.